# What role provides access to the Replica-Set status method (rs.status()) for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I would like to create a user that just has access to retrieve the status of our replica-set. Is there a built-in or other role that allows this? The docs do not seem to indicate what role is even needed to call any of `rs.` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the "clusterMonitor" role.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor.